# get the name of a file without empty spaces

Tags: c#

I´m working in a MVC project and receive a file(HttpPostedFileBase property) in my controller via modelbinding and what I want is to delete all the empty spaces in the name of the file I just received, for that purpose I use this

```
 var nombre_archivo = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm.") +"_"+ (info.file.FileName.ToString()).Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but the var "nombre_archivo" is always: 201801240942.System.String[] and what I want is 201801240942.nameOfFile, could you please tell me where is the error?

Comment: If you want to replace strings, use `String.Replace(string,string)`, eg `String.Replace(" ","")`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is how you should be able to fix your problem

```
string nombre_archivo = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm."), info.file.FileName.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
```

**EDIT :** 
You should use string.Replace instead of using Linq query.
There is a format problem I did not expect.

So, the right answer is given below, but basically, it would look like :

```
string nombre_archivo = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm."), info.file.FileName.Replace(" ", ""));
```

Comment: Yes, I know, I dislike using string.Replace() to remove whitespaces because of semantic.
People downvoting, could you explain in what way string.Replace is better ? :-)

Comment: @Florian what semantic? If anything it's the LINQ query that causes confusion and slow performance.

Comment: @Florian and the wrong output. There's no implicit conversion from an Enumerable to a string. This code produces `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Char]`

Comment: Indeed.  This question is downvoted because it does not give the correct result.  Its a shame its the accepted answer.

Comment: @Florian `Replace` is better because it describes what is actually happening, you are replacing spaces with nothing.  In the linq example, the code literally reads as "give me an enumeration of characters that are not whitespace".  I'm not even sure if `Format` will convert an enumeration of characters into a string representation again.

Comment: I tried the code, and you are right about the format problem.
I should have tried it before posting. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Your are splitting on an array of dots.

Use `replace` instead :

```
var nombre_archivo = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
                         DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm."),
                         info.file.FileName.replace(" ", "")
);
```

Moreover, we recommend to use `string.Format` instead of `+` concatenation. It's faster and clearer

Comment: There's no `replace` method. You can't specify an empty character. You probably meant `.Replace(" ","")`

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm.")}_{info.file.FileName.Replace(" ", "")}";
```

Comment: There's no `String.replace` method

Comment: No, he is right. string.Replace() exists, string.replace() doesn't !

Comment: @Florian He should specify it's a syntax error, then. [Because String.Replace() definitely exists.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I already did, in the other, almost identical answer that was posted 12 minutes before this. Answers should *compile* at the very least

Comment: That's not a syntax error.  `String.replace(" ", "")` is syntactically correct in that it conforms to the rules for the C# language grammar.  The symbol `replace` does not exist.  This is a semantic error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Replace` to replace a space with an empty string. The method has other issues though. It doesn't check whether `FileName` is valid which means someone could make a POST request with a hand-coded path like `../../` or `E:\somepath\myinnocentprogram.exe` to write a file to the server's disk. Or worse, `../index.htm`.

Replacing spaces doesn't make much sense. It's the dots and slashes that can result

If you check [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/) you'll see that the author uses `Path.GetFileName()` to retrieve only the file's name before saving it in the proper folder. Your code should look like this::

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)
                       .Replace(" ","");
    var finalName=String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddHHmm}._{1}",DateTime.Now,fileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), finalName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This ensures that only the filename part of the file is used, and that the file is saved in the appropriate folder, even if someone posted an invalid path